# Reflection Exception Guard Contract Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a basic middleware in Laravel 5.0 but somehow I donot understand that its using the same namespace for the Guard Contract as of my middleware. Below is the code and exception that I am looking at.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware; 
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class LoginMiddleWare {
/**
 * Gaurd Implementation
 * @var Gaurd
 */

protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new filter instance.
 *
 * @param  Guard  $auth
 * @return void
 */

public function __construct(Gaurd $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!$this->auth->check())
    {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}

}
```

> ReflectionException in compiled.php line 1050:
>   Class App\Http\Middleware\Gaurd does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I think so find out the solution.
It was a typo mistake from my side.